# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'. Request Method:

Tags: django-forms

I create a form where users can create a team. At first, the creation is working. But, after I worked out the team-detail-view I cannot create a team again.
Here is the detail-view:

```
def team(request, id, **kwargs):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        team.instance.team = team
        return redirect(reverse('team-detail', kwargs={
            'id': team.id
    }))
    context = {
        'team': team,
    }
    return render(request, 'club.html', context)
```

And the now the create-view:

```
def team_create_view(request, id):
    title = 'Create'
    form = TeamCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    coach = get_coach(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            new_team = form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("club", kwargs={'id': form.instance.id }))
    else:
        form = TeamCreateForm()   
    context = {'title': title,'form': form}
    return render(request, "team_create.html", context)
```

url.py

```
    path('team/<id>/', team, name='team-detail'),
    path('team/create/', team_create_view, name='team-create'),
```

Comment: You not pass `id` form url (`team-detail'`). `def team_create_view(request, id):` please remove `id`. like this `def team_create_view(request):`

Comment: I remove it as suggest but I get the same error.

Comment: please add you model. `team_create_view` this function for add new team ??

Comment: if team exist then update it ??otherwise insert ??